# Combine Two Dataframes based on specific column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with different shapes (number of rows and columns differ).

df1

ticketid    descp     alertname

1           3000       nsp
2           1000       rsp
3           5000       gsp

df2

ticketid    vol   prd    technology

1            30   scom     soft
3            45   dess      hard
6            34   scom      soft
7            35   scom      hard

I need to combine these two dataframes based on ticketid column. the new dataframe must have all values from df1 and whatever matches in df2(based on ticketid) those rows also need to be added.

I want the new dataframe to be like this

ticketid     descp      alertname      vol      prd        technology

1           3000          nsp          30      scom       soft
3           5000          gsp          45      dess       hard

How to do this in pandas`

Comment: You can use `left` join on `ticketid` column @lakshith

Comment: Yes I did. it throws the following error. ValueError: The column label 'TicketID' is not unique.

Comment: df1.merge(df2,on="TicketID",how="left"). I tried left, outer, inner...but all ends up throwing error - ValueError: The column label 'TicketID' is not unique.

Comment: Try `df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on="ticketid",how='left')`. You have provided the output dataframe, if you want to do a left join, then row `2 1000 rsp` from df1 should also essentially be a part of the output @lakshith

Comment: yes tried. Same error - ValueError: The column label 'TicketID' is not unique.

Comment: This `df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on="ticketid",how='left')` works fine, I tried it with your dataframe!